# Reduce width of dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I have two pages of code. I want the first page's dropdown menu to look like the second page's dropdown menu. The second page is some code I copied and pasted from W3 Schools.

The problem is on the first page the drop down menu's width is the same as the navigation bar. I want to have a smaller width for the navigation bar and I can't figure out how why it is the same width of navigation bar.

First Page

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropcont {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333 min-width:200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropcont a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropcont {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home"> Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home1"> Your Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home2">Home Sales</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#home3" class="dropbtn">Home profile</a>
    <div class="dropcont">
      <a href="#home2">Home2</a>
      <a href="#home3">Home3</a>
      <a href="#home4">Home4</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Second Page

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: could you please share fiddle for your code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated css :

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:green;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color:#333;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropcont {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropcont a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropcont a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropcont {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home"> Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home1"> Your Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home2">Home Sales</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#home3" class="dropbtn">Home profile</a>
    <div class="dropcont">
      <a href="#home2">Home2</a>
      <a href="#home3">Home3</a>
      <a href="#home4">Home4</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```